# Android device is not showing the background image

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have created a project, targeting `android 4.4 - API Level 19`, as suggested by eclipse.

Anyways, on the emulator everything looks perfect - here is a screenshot:

[image: app screenshot]

The problems comes when I install it on my real device - running android `4.1.2`. Everything is just perfect and working like a charm, excepting the background image. It is showing a white background, like the picture does not exists.

Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/wg_blurred_backgrounds_12"
>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnTopJokes" 
    android:onClick="showTopJokes"   
    android:gravity="center" 
/>

<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnNewJokes" 
    android:onClick="showNewJokes" 
    android:gravity="center"
/>

<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnAllJokes" 
    android:onClick="showAllJokes" 
    android:gravity="center"
/>

<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnMyFavorites" 
    android:onClick="showFavorites" 
    android:gravity="center"
/>

<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnCategories" 
    android:onClick="showCategories"
    android:gravity="center"
/>

<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnAddNewJoke" 
    android:gravity="center"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Isn't `android:background="@drawable/wg_blurred_backgrounds_12` working on android `4.1.2` ?

Do I have to change anything in the premissions? Here is what I have now:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I know that I miss something really small, but I'm not able to spot it as a beginner.

Comment: do you the drawable in the respective drawable folder? check this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @Raghunandan yes everything is just fine.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try with a lower-resolution background. The one you are trying might be too big. You can check that in your logcat.

Comment: I have no problems on the emulator. I can see the background there. It is not showing on my nexus s with android `4.1.2`

Comment: Have you tried to create the drawable folder and put the lower-resolution background inside ? I have encountered this problem, I do not remember exactly how to solve it. But it is something like this.

Comment: Some lolipop devices wouldn't show with higher resolution images. This fix works. You could also manually resize the bitmap programmatically if you generate the backgrounds randomly or use a set of images to load them into the background.

Answer (score 15):

In your logcat you will see a message like this:

`Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2496x4437, max=4096x4096)`

The max is `4096x4096` which is the value `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` for the version of OpenGL that is running on the device.

Answer (score 6):

you may need to add this to your manifest file .
android:hardwareAccelerated="false" , android:largeHeap="true"

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing those underscores given to the name of the drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Need to check drawable size.Add the image in four resolutions.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Save the image in every folder of drawable like in xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi with respect to thier resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Decrease Height And Width of the Image . This will solve problem . You can see image too large error generated by logcat also

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it doesn't say `(24)` or `(v 24)` next to the image file you have in your drawable file, re-copy the image and make it save it as the type with no `(24)` in it as it will prepare it to be used for `API 24` and above, my phone uses that's why it failed on my part `API 23`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to disable hardware acceleration to the view you are setting background

myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)

and then set the background