# Failure retrieving resources

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I created a simple app and set Background of LinearLayout to an image. when i run it, don't show background image. i see this line of log:

```
W/PackageManager﹕ Failure retrieving resources for vania.backgroundtest: Resource ID #0x0
```

why can't show background image?
This is my Layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backimage"
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

and this is manifest:

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

i used a .jpg image with 1920*1080 (412 KB)

Comment: Can you provide more code ? How do you set the background image ?

Comment: You could try with a smaller image. I don't think it'll change much, but it's worth a try, because maybe there's some memory image.
Besides, are you sure the image is not corrupted? Try to open it with an image editor. 
And lastly, is the LinearLayout shown at all? Maybe for some other layout items, the LinearLayout isn't  shown at all and we're focusing on the wrong problem.

Comment: That's true! problem solved with resize image to 1280*720. but why?

Comment: Hi, Is it solved for u?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `android:background`property of the LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/myimage"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- More elements --> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Where `myimage` is a correct image in `the res/drawable directory`. You can find more details in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Comment: This is my Code: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backimage">
</LinearLayout>

Comment: Use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`. But I don't think it will correct your problem. Can you post your xml and java code ?

Comment: Did you try with a lower-resolution background ?

Comment: yes, problem solved with resize image to 1280*720. but why?

Comment: Which device / emulator are you using ? I found this [thred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434070/android-device-is-not-showing-the-background-image) which suggests to use a lower resolution. Maybe your resolution was to high for your device ? You should think about using [qualifier](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) like `ldpi`, `mdpi`, ...

Comment: I used HTC One M7 (4.7 inch, Full HD 1080p, 468 PPI)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92963/discussion-between-maloubobola-and-msafdel).