# Background ImageView is not Shown in API level 16 though working good in API 19

Tags: android, background, imageview, visibility

I am not able to find out the exact issue that **why the image(background) is not visible in API level 16 but it is showing good in API level 19**. I have worked simply as i have done previously but , this time the background is not shown(of WaterMark in ImageView).
I am not able to find out what is exact issue . So i need help.I have done every thing as suggested in the stack [Android device is not showing the background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434070/android-device-is-not-showing-the-background-image/22434547) but it is not going good in my case.

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rlGetInTouch"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#304EA2">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/header_bg2">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/brand"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/nbl_logo4" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#304EA2">





 <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"
                        android:color="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:src="@drawable/logowatermark" />


                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="35dp"
                    android:paddingRight="35dp">


                    <******.CustomFontLoginTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text=" Please login to proceed"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />


                    <******.CustomFontEditText
                        android:id="@+id/etUsername"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:hint="Mobile Number"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="@integer/mobile_length"
                        android:padding="13dp"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <******.CustomFontEditText
                        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/passwordVisibilityBtn"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:hint="Password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:maxLength="@integer/password_length"
                        android:padding="13dp"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <******.CustomFontCheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/chkSaveUsername"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
                        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="  Remember Mobile No."
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/loginLl"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:background="@drawable/login_button_shadow"
                        android:orientation="vertical">


                        <******.CustomFontLoginTextView
                            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:background="@drawable/login_button_new1"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="13dp"
                            android:text="Login"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />


                        <******.CustomFontLoginTextView
                            android:id="@+id/action_sms"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/login_button_new1"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                            android:paddingRight="20dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Switch To SMS"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">


                        <******.CustomFontLoginTextView
                            android:id="@+id/resetDeviceId"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:alpha="0.7"
                            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_reset_20"
                            android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/reset_device_id_text"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <******.CustomFontLoginTextView
                            android:id="@+id/action_info"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:alpha="0.7"
                            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_info_20"
                            android:drawablePadding="3dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/info"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    </RelativeLayout>


                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>


            <!-- Promo -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llPromotions"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/promo_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llBranches"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rlLogin"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#304EA2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="showATMs"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_atm_50_6" />

                    <******.CustomFontLoginTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="ATM"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <******.CustomFontLoginTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="3dp"
                        android:text="Locate nearest Atm Machines"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="8sp" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="showBranches"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_branches_50_6" />

                    <******.CustomFontLoginTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:text="BRANCHES"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <******.CustomFontLoginTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="3dp"
                        android:text="Locate nearest bank branches"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="8sp" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="showRates"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_rates_50_6" />

                    <******.CustomFontLoginTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="RATES"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <******.CustomFontLoginTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="3dp"
                        android:text="Foreign exchange and stock rates"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="8sp" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlProducts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <******.CustomFontLoginTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Products"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <!--Product Container-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <!--Product 1-->
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/product_content1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="7.5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical" />


                    <!--Product 2-->
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/product_content2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7.5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:orientation="vertical" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlGetInTouch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#304EA2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CustomFontLoginTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnCall"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Get in touch with us"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
        <!--app:maxTextSize="14sp"
        app:minTextSize="@dimen/minFontSize"-->

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnMap"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:onClick="showLocation"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_location_24_4" />

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnEmail"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnMap"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnMap"
            android:onClick="openEmail"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_mail_24_4" />

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnCall"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnEmail"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnEmail"
            android:onClick="openCall"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_call_24_4" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> The Image background of watermark is not shown. I have done nothing
>   new ,same as previous but dont' know that is the exact issue.

Comment: why  **`android:color="@android:color/transparent"`** inside `imageview`

Comment: @NileshRathod  i am checking everything..Without adding that also not solved my problem

Comment: @seon what are you trying to provide the background to?

Comment: @G.hakim i am trying Watermark logo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just Removed marginTop and it worked fine in API level 16

```
<ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"

                        android:src="@drawable/logowatermark" />
```

> I don't understand that why it worked when i remove the -ve marginTop
>   in above? .I got solution but don't understand what exactly happened
>   in adding -ve marginTop and with removing -ve marginTop.

Answer (score 0):

Please reduce image size to visible in the lower level device.